# How would I deduce a≠c from a≠b and b≠c in Fitch?

Tags: logic, symbolic-logic, fitch

How would I deduce a≠c from the premises a≠b and b≠c in Fitch? 
This is what I've done so far.

b=b (=Intro)

b≠a (Ana Con)

b≠c (Reit)

And then for some reason I get stuck here? 
I know this sounds simple, but I'm lost! Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can't, because it isn't valid. Think about it with numbers, consider:

> a=1 
>   b=2 
>   c=1

It's true that a≠b & b≠c, yet a=c.